# is it possible to run jQuery slideup() and animate() parallely

Tags: jquery-ui

I want `slideup()` and `animate()` to run on different elements in parallel using jQuery. Is there any way to achieve this??

Here is my current code..

```
$('#div1').slideUp(100);
$('#div2').animate({top:'-=20px'});
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? (aside from the syntax error, should be `top:'-20px'`)

Comment: With the above code, slideup is exexuted first and then margin top takes effect. I wanted both effects to happen simultaneously

Comment: What do you mean "margin top takes effect". Does it animate at all?

Comment: Yes it animates after slideup() of div.

Comment: Something else is affecting it then, because those two functions are asynchronous (the slide up will start and then the animation will start, without waiting for the slide to finish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your jquery version first.
Currently:

> .slideUp( [duration ] [, complete ] )
>
> ```
> duration (default: 400)
> ```
>
> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
>
> ```
> duration (default: 400)
> ```

So in your case, the functions are asynchronous and both have the same duration. Which means, they should start and stop at (close to) the same time. It might be, depends on the elements properties, your animations look like they do things faster, but that should not be the case!

**Example:**
SlideUp a 10000 pixel height element looks much faster than slideUp a 100 pixel height element. But the duration is the same.